# Package guit with ltugboat gives an error

Tags: errors, tugboat

This MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[final]{ltugboat} 
\usepackage{guit}
\begin{document} 
    It worked a week ago 
    \GuITmeeting[style=inline,year=2019]!   
\end{document}
```

gives this error

```
! No declaration for shape OT1/pzc/mb/it.
sub@sfcnt ...e forspace shapespace mandatory@arg }
                                                  error@fontshape else #1{Fo...
l.6     \GuITmeeting[style=inline,year=2019]
                                         !  
? 
! Emergency stop.
```

It worked till a week ago.

If it could be useful, this is the beginning of my log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.2.27)  29 FEB 2020 07:45
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**errore.ltx
(./errore.ltx
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2020-02-25>
```

Comment: I will look. Which latex patch level are you using?

Comment: There should a bit later a line starting with latex and a date and a patch level.

Comment: There should a bit later a line starting with latex and a date and a patch level.

Comment: Yes. I will check in a few minutes but there is the hope that patch level 5 uploaded yesterday will resolve it.

Comment: Try to compile with pdflatex-dev instead.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer With pdflatex-dev it works

Comment: I just got LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5 and it compiles without error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It works, would you like to add an answer? Thank you!